# Cannot load texture of CG object when using GLTF loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, gltf

I’m trying to load GLTF file in my React file. I was able to load the CG object (dog!), however texture is not applied. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I’m using async function to load the CG.

I use this function to load the file:

```
async function loadModal() {
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  const object = await loader.loadAsync("/low_poly_dog/scene.gltf"); 
  const scene = object.scene;
  scene.scale.setScalar(8.5);

  return scene;
}
```

dogRef.current = dog object itself.

```
loadModal().then((model) => {
      if (dogRef.current) {
        scene.remove(dogRef.current);
      }
      dogRef.current = model;
      dogRef.current.position.copy(
        overlay.latLngAltitudeToVector3(props.mapOptions.center)
      );
      dogRef.current.rotateY(-45);
      overlay.scene.add(dogRef.current);
});
```

Comment: Start by testing the model in a viewer. If the texture is missing there, your export isn't working. If the texture is shown in the viewer, you probably need to set up better lighting.

Answer (score 0):

I previewed the model using https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and figured out that texture was not applied. When I replaced with other model, it was loaded with texture.